# Next Previous navigation in news article for umbraco

Tags: xslt, xpath, navigation, umbraco

This is driving me a little crazy (been trying to do this for quite some time)

I'm trying to get some xpath code working that will display next and previous links, which will take you to the next newsItem and once it gets to newsItem4, then the next button disappears.

```
<newsArea>
  <newsItem1></newsItem1>   <----- currentPage
  <newsItem2></newsItem2>
  <newsItem3></newsItem3>
  <newsItem4></newsItem4>
</newsArea>
```

I can list al the newsItems whilst on  a news item with

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/../*">
   <h2><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></h2>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

and i can count how many items i have

```
<xsl:value-of select="count($currentPage/../*)-1"/>
```

but i dont know how to move to the next news item, or how to tell it when to stop showing the next node when it comes to the end of the newsItems (one example just jummped to another leve)

Any help would be really really appreciated.

Thanks

Tim

Comment: It seems that your question and the provided XML document are out of sync -- there is no `nodeName` attribute at all in the document. Please, correct.

Comment: Also I assume you need html, so you need to provide the desired html output.

Comment: If `$currentPage` is a singleton node set with `newsItem1` element, then `$currentPage/following-sibling::*[1]` will select the `newsItem1`...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the paging sample from this blog post: http://www.nibble.be/?p=11

That should give you an idea of how it works.  You could always set your page size to 1.

Also, there is a package based on that method: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/paging-xslt

That should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create a "Page Navigation" macro to add to the bottom of any template you want it, XSLT would be as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- if there's a previous page -->
  <xsl:if test="$currentPage/preceding-sibling::*[1]">
    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($currentPage/preceding-sibling::*[1]/@id)}">&lt; Prev</a>
  </xsl:if>
  <!-- if there's next and previous, show divider -->
  <xsl:if test="$currentPage/preceding-sibling::*[1] and $currentPage/following-sibling::*[1]">
    <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <!-- if there's a next page -->
  <xsl:if test="$currentPage/following-sibling::*[1]">
    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($currentPage/following-sibling::*[1]/@id)}">Next &gt;</a>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```